# ¿Como usar bootstrap en laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

Acabo de crear un nuevo proyecto laravel e introduje el comando **npm i** para instalar bootstrap.
Ahora, al crear una nueva plantilla blade, *¿como llamo al **css** y **js** de boostrap desde **home.blade.php**?*  Intenté con **app.js** y **app.css** que están en la carpeta **public**, pero no me funcionan las utilidades como las **Navs** a menos que incluya directamente el *cnd* que da la plantilla de inicio de [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/).

Comment: Tengo una duda, en el fronted(.blade), utilizas solo `javascript`? o tienes algo como: `react`, `vue.js`, `angular` o alguno similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que importar la libreria en tu hoja de estilo:

CSS:

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

SCSS:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

JS:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
```

y luego lo tienes en:

```
<link href="{{ asset(mix('css/app.css')) }}" rel="stylesheet">
...
<script src="{{ asset(mix('js/app.js')) }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar el preset `bootstrap` que trae el paquete `laravel/ui`:

[Andamiaje JavaScript y CSS](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend)

Si bien Laravel no dicta qué preprocesadores de JavaScript o CSS utilizar, sí proporciona un punto de partida básico usando Bootstrap. Por defecto, Laravel usa NPM para instalar los paquetes frontend.

El andamiaje Bootstrap proporcionado por Laravel se encuentra en el paquete `laravel/ui`, que puede instalarse usando Composer:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Una vez que se haya instalado el paquete `laravel/ui`, puedes instalar el andamiaje frontend utilizando el comando Artisan `ui`:

```
// Generar andamiaje básicos para Bootstrap ...
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

Instala las dependencias frontend de tu proyecto utilizando el administrador de paquetes de node (NPM):

```
npm install
```

Una vez que las dependencias se han instalado usando `npm install`, puedes compilar tus archivos usando Laravel Mix. El comando `npm run dev` procesará las instrucciones en tu archivo `webpack.mix.js`.

```
npm run dev
```

*Nota*: Por defecto, el archivo Laravel `package.json` incluye algunos paquetes como `lodash` y `axios` para ayudarte a comenzar a construir tu aplicación JavaScript. Siéntete libre de agregar o eliminar del archivo `package.json` según sea necesario para tu aplicación.

Finalmente, en tu vista principal carga los archivos compilados:

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```