# Laravel - Webpack no me genera el archivo css

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, webpack, laravel-7

Estoy intentando configurar webpack para laravel 7 y tengo este fichero **webpack.mix.js**, por un lado tengo los JS, luego los css de vendors (boostrap) y luego mi propio sass

```
   mix.js([
          'resources/assets/vendor/popper/popper.min.js',
          'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js',
          'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
          'resources/assets/vendor/boostrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.js',
          'resources/assets/vendor/boostrap-table/bootstrap-table-es-ES.min.js',
          'resources/assets/js/app.js',
   ], 'public/js/app.js')
    .css([
        'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css',
        'resources/assets/vendor/boostrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.css',
        'resources/assets/vendor/twitter-boostrap/bootstrap.css',
        'resources/assets/vendor/twitter-boostrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css',
        ],'public/css/app.css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app2.css');
```

Como vereis los css los intento compilar en un archivo que sea **app.css** y los sass en un archivo **app2.css**

Al ejecutar un npm run watch o npm run dev la salida que tengo por pantalla es esta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como vereis me genera el archivo app2.css pero **no me genera el archivo app.css**

Por más que miro la documentación no consigo ver mi fallo.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como usar bootstrap en laravel 7?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358148/como-usar-bootstrap-en-laravel-7)

Comment: No gracias, encontré la solución cuando me deje la publico.